# Android SQLite limit 0,60 than 60,120... i get more?

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to get the first 60 rows, than the next 60....

This is my Cursor

```
final Cursor cursor = myDbSales.searchNamemagic(name, startLong, endLong,  limita,  limitb);

public  Cursor searchNamemagic(String search_str, String startdate, String enddate, String limita , String limitb) {

    try {

        int firstSpace = search_str.indexOf(" "); // detect the first space character
        firstName = search_str.substring(0, firstSpace);  // get everything upto the first space character
        lastName = search_str.substring(firstSpace).trim(); // get everything after the first space, trimming the spaces off
        }catch (Exception c){}

    String query = "SELECT * ,  strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', datetime(timeStamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) as timecrazy   , tastepreis/(tax+100.0)*tax as'"+TAXSUMSEARCHNAME+"',    '"+currency+"' as '"+ DOLLA_SIGN+"' FROM salesTable where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"' AND (sellid LIKE '%"+search_str+"%'  OR tastemodel LIKE '%"+search_str+"%'  OR bezeichnung LIKE '%"+search_str+"%' OR sellid LIKE '%"+lastName+" "+firstName +"%'       )  ORDER BY timeStamp DESC limit '"+limita+"', '"+limitb+"'   " ;

    Cursor mCursor = dbSales.rawQuery(query, null);




    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

And this is my method

```
method(name,imyourlist1,"0","60" );
            method(name,imyourlist2, "60","120" );
            method(name,imyourlist3, "120","180");
            method(name,imyourlist4, "180","240");
            method(name,imyourlist5, "240","300");
            v(name,imyourlist6, "300","360");
            method(name,imyourlist7, "360","420");
            method(name,imyourlist8, "420","480");
            method(name,imyourlist9 ,"480","540");
            method(name,imyourlist10 ,"540","600" );

private void method (String name ,ListView imyourlist2, String limita, String limitb){

        final Cursor cursor = myDbSales.searchNamemagic(name, startLong, endLong,  limita,  limitb)
```

imyourlist1 is correct with 60 Rows but the next ones get more.

For example first one = 0-60 next one 60-more than 120

Is maybe my limit wrong?

Comment: what do you need it for? for a "paged" list view?

Comment: I create multiple ListViews to get 10 PDF Pages with Android KitKat PDFDOCUMENT api

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 60 OFFSET 0
```

Next 60

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 60 OFFSET 1
```

Page Number is int

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 60 OFFSET Number
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmad, should it not be FROM tableName LIMIT 0 OFFSET 60 for the next tableName LIMIT 60 OFFSET 120?